# How to make rounded images

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make rounded images like [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=circle%20image&espv=210&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&imgil=2hjFDBYIe_Vz6M%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcR2iBp-aOe8wDmVCYTBCgkSLl40dZVr1NtLLjlC4a0f806NChCamw%253B600%253B600%253BGFesGOjn2dCEeM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fcommons.wikimedia.org%25252Fwiki%25252FFile%25253ASki_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg&source=iu&usg=__V9g3cSCccaCqgqkdGRx6UcaA-OQ=&sa=X&ei=uMb4UvqZOoeMrQfH9ICQDw&sqi=2&ved=0CC4Q9QEwAg&biw=1024&bih=677) I have searched and googled but I did not find any solutions to make image rounded.I can do images [rounded border](http://bootply.com/112365) like this but I dont know how to make the image itself rounded.Please help

Comment: Use `border-radius: 50%` on the image itself. Like [so](http://jsfiddle.net/pCejj/).

Comment: Just increase the border-radius to 50% in the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Change radius by adjusting `height` and `width`. `height` and `width` should be equal and double of the radius you required

**HTML :**

```
<div id="round">
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#round{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gAXpP/1/) / updated

Check this for responsive circle [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/gAXpP/8/)

Comment: Use `overflow:hidden;` property as well if you are applying it on `div`, not `img` :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1.But please tell me why kunj has suggested to use overflow:hidden

Comment: while content of div is overflowed it will show scroll-bar, to avoid that we need to use `overflow:hidden;` it will hide the part that is overflowed

Comment: The overlow is necessary because (in the example) the radius was not applied to the image but rather the surrounding div. Some older browsers will not permit border-radius on images.

Comment: @rocking because above example applying border radius on `div`, not `img` which supposed to use in it (thanks Pranav and Paulie who already explained it).

Comment: Is it responsive,I am using bootstrap for my app.So can I use your way?

Comment: @PranavCBalan If I change the screensize then image size is not changing

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks for the answer and the the fiddles.Well what I want is I have a users photo to be shown on a webpage.But the photo I want in circular way(generaly we have photos in square manner).It does not matter if the face is visible or not but the photo I want is in circular manner.The last link you have given is green colour background with an image embedded in it.I dont want this way.I want the image it self be rounded

Answer (score 2):

Use `border-radius` to achieve what you are looking for.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkgdz/1/)**

**The code:**

```
img{border-radius:50%;}
```

Comment: Yes it is responsive - @rocking

Comment: If I use your way then all the images present will be of round shaped,right?

Comment: Right. It will be rounded - @rocking

Comment: This is more responsive, as it is in Percentage. http://jsfiddle.net/Zkgdz/2/ But if you are going to declare media queries, then you can go with my first solution i.e http://jsfiddle.net/Zkgdz/1 too - @rocking

Comment: But If i change the screen sizes then image size is not changing

Comment: if you want to make it responsive , then both width and height should be same. To make that you need to use jQuery or javascript

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically want a white box with a rounded image in it, you simply make a div with the said width & height you want.
Give it a background color and a border of  1px in the same background color.
Then in the div place an image with borderradius of 50% and width and height of 100% to fill the box and you're done.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/fWwgD/

```
<style type="text/css">
 body
  {
  background-color:black;
  }
#box 
  {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  }
.circle 
  {
  border-radius:50%;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
</style>
<div id="box">
   <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/01f40d1a1219433e2f7ab40fab531142?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="circle">
</div>
```